# is there a way to detect if my configure profile installed or not on IPhone?

Tags: installation, profile, configure

What i am trying to do is to send a configure profile to user to install on his iphone.

once my application start up, it will check if that configure profile has been installed or not?

is there any way to implement such function like this?

Thanks.

Comment: i have figured it out from Apple developer forum to learn a workaround  to check certificate tied with configuration profile.